# Adding a separate CSS file in the body

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have provided a template and it contains many CSS files in head and the body is divided into **header ,content and footer** portions. I want to add to add bootstrap in order to utilize its grid system for its content part. But when ever I add bootstrap.css in head above or below all the style sheets in `<head>` content part and footer part renders well but my header portion of the body encounter certain design problems as many of the properties in other css files get overridden by its grid system.

> All I want to know is, is there any hack I may be able to use the
>   bootstrap.css for the content part?

I have also tried linking the bootstrap file in `<body>` below the `<header>` and above the content portion(I know its not a good practice.) . but it also causes the similar problems for the header portion.

Comment: http://vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is make and download a custom bootstrap version from http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ that contains only the grid system and use that CSS in your web app.

Comment: Absolutely ow some and perfect saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You're going to either have to change your markup and adjust the styles accordingly, or use an ID wrapper and change the styles in your CSS to only target `<header>` under that specific ID.

You're better off adjusting your styles to fit bootstrap, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `!important` to the properties that you want to customize in your CSS file.

But the best way I see to solve your issue is modifying the `bootstrap.css` file adding your configurations and adding `!important` if necessary

Comment: @n01ze why? He can just download the `bootstrap.css` file, edit it as he wants and import it, can't he?

Comment: But he has no better chance, has he?

Comment: Yup but there are a lot of css files near about 9-10 its hard to go through all of them and changing. :(

Comment: just add `!important` to your attributes and it'll override all the other assignations to it

Comment: lets find out which and all styles are over ridden and remove style from bootstrap.css. And its a bad practice.